# ¿Como hacer que un AlertDialog se ejecute una sola vez al inicio de una Activity?

Tags: java, android

Tengo un mensaje de alerta que esta en el main activity y que se ejecuta al momento de ingresar a esa activity, como puedo hacer que el mensaje de alerta se muestre una sola vez, es decir, que cuando este por ejemplo en la activity 2 y vuelva al main activity el mensaje no se vuelva a mostrar

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Importante");
    builder.setMessage("Recuerda activar el GPS para obtener tu ubicación");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK",null);
    builder.create();
    builder.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes controlar usando `SharedPreferences` el proceso es.

A la pantalla splashScreen establecer la variable bandera `firstRun=true`

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("MY_APP_FLAGS", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putBoolean("first_run",true).apply();
```

A la pantalla donde muestras el dialogo, antes de mostrarlo compruebas si `firstRun==true` y al mostrarlo estableces `firstRun=false`

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("MY_APP_FLAGS", 0);
boolean firstRun = sp.getBoolean("first_run",true);

if (firstRun) {
   //Lanzar la Alerta
   firstRun = false;
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
   editor.putBoolean("first_run",firstRun).apply();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

podrias utilizar una variable booleana por ejemplo e implementarla, de la siguiente manera, tan solo es una humilde opinion

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean activar = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (activar) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Importante");
            builder.setMessage("Recuerda activar el GPS para obtener tu ubicación");
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            builder.create();
            builder.show();
            activar = false;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("PRIMERAVEZSP", 0);
    boolean primeravez = sp.getBoolean("primeravez",false);
    if(primeravez)
        {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Importante");
    builder.setMessage("Recuerda activar el GPS para obtener tu ubicación"); builder.setPositiveButton("OK",null); 
    builder.create(); 
    builder.show(); 
   }  
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
   editor.putBoolean("primeravez",false);
   editor.apply();
}
```

En la actividad de Splash

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("PRIMERAVEZSP", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit(); editor.putBoolean("primeravez",true);
       editor.apply();
```